# How to install Solaris Studio 12 on Solaris 10 used as a guest OS using VMWare player on Windows 7?

Tags: vmware

I have installed Solaris 10 OS as a guest OS using VM Player in Windows 7 (host OS). Now I want to install Solaris Studio 12 in my guest OS. How to do this?

My system is using x86 based 32-bit processor.

Answer (score 1):

I've never installed Studio on Solaris within VMWare but I have installed Studio
on Solaris running in a VirtualBox, so perhaps this may be of some help.

The Studio installer is unaware of any virtual environment. As long as it sees
that it is installing on Solaris, then you should be able to run the product installer script
just as if it was on a bare metal Solaris. That's what worked for me.
If you have a problem, you can always just get the Studio product as a tarball and
un-tar it into whatever directory you want.
Either way, you will need to change your PATH variable to find the Studio executables.

Final comment, the latest Studio product is 12.3, so I would download and install that version.
Its available in both Solaris 10 package and tar-ball form on the Oracle Technology website.
See: oracle.com/goto/SolarisStudio